# Enabling the memory controller on cgroup v2 on fedora 34

Tags: fedora, cgroups, kubernetes, container

I am trying to install kubernetes on a fedora34 machine. The preflight fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR SystemVerification]: missing required cgroups: memory
```

I have been trying to find out where this comes from, and what to do about it. So far with no success. What I found out is that fedora 34 uses cgroups v2 by default. And according to the docs you can finds out which controllers are active the following way:

```
[root@pi43 cgroup]# cat cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu io pids
```

And there I see no mention of memory.

According to the official [cgroups v2 doc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tj/cgroup.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.rst) enabling a controller is done by writing to cgroup.subtree_control

```
[root@pi43 cgroup]# echo "+memory" > cgroup.subtree_control
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

However, as you see in the above example, this does not work as expected.

So I am stuck. How do I solve this?